# How to avoid Edit Text to overwrite on Text View

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am new to Android and I made a Edit text in which user can enter his email id but when he enters the wrong Email then I show message within the text box to the right "Invalid User" by making it visible, the problem is if user email is very long then the message will come over it and I want to avoid it.
Here is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailedittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="To my first character"
      >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="INVALID USER "
        android:visibility="gone"

       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is email edittext & textview for the message ?

Comment: show java code: showing "text box".

Comment: instead of using 

        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

You could use the attribute android:layout_below="@id/password" to show the error textView below the password field

Comment: Just updated it was wrongly typed as password instead of email

Comment: I want to show meassge to the right of email only

Comment: @ViDuR i'll suggest you to use [Dialog](http://goo.gl/f0VEeI) or [Toast](http://goo.gl/4zocin) to display message or error , you can also use [setError](http://goo.gl/wnoKZa) for Edit Text. still i tried to give & posted answer to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is,

1. Clear the value of edit text before showing error message
2. Set the background color of text view same as the background color od edit text. SO that, the portion below text view won't be visible to the user

Answer (score 1):

Since you are giving `emailedittext` width as a `match_parent` it will fit to its parent.

And for the textview which you wants to use for displaying message should have proper layout params like alignment `toRightOf` (if you wants besided edit text) etc which is missed.

So if you wants to display besides `emailedittext` use give `toRightOf`  to TextView & fix width to edittext. To display below give `layout_below`

Here i trid to give answer with code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailedittext"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="To my first character"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="helloworld_android@androiduser.com">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/emailedittext"
        android:text="INVALID USER "

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OR**
***For linear use weight***

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailedittext"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_weight="7"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="To my first character"
    android:lines="2"
    android:text="helloworld_android@androiduser.com">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="INVALID USER "

    />
```

***Suggestion***

For mobile app try to give message as a Alert or Toast. avoid displaying message like this in textview .

For edit text use [setError](http://goo.gl/wnoKZa) to display alert or for user attention.
Below one sample i have given with [setError](http://goo.gl/Zii6Uz) which is used for edit text

```
     final EditText emailedittext = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.emailedittext);

         findViewById(R.id.btnSelect).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailedittext.getText().toString())) {
                    emailedittext.setError("Please enter email id");
                } else {
//                    if (emailid is not proper/valid) {
//                        emailedittext.setError("Please enter valid Email id");
//                    } else {
//                        // Correct email
//                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the align parents and simply give width,height,id and layout below attribute for the TextView.Then u can see one below the other as u have given a relative layout

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    ... >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:weight="2"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        ... />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:weight="1"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

This way when msg TextView is hidden email will take full width. When msg is visible,  email will take 2/3 rd width and msg will take 1/3rd width.